# Count unique ids on right table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM class_members WHERE class_id = 1;
```

Which  returns the following result:

```
class_id | user_id
   1     |   2
   1     |   1
   1     |   3
   1     |   5
```

I want to count all the unique user_ids per class.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM class_members WHERE class_id = 1;` - done.

Comment: @FDL thank yuu for the answer it worked great!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  class_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        class_id
```